# Cast function pointer to (void*)

Tags: c++, casting, function-pointers

I have a simple question which is breaking my mind.
On my solution, I'm working with a DLL that offers me the following function:

```
int RegisterCallback(TCallbackType CallbackType, void *pLLTProfileCallback, void *pUserData);
```

For more information, the parameter pLLTProfileCallback is a function type defined as:

```
typedef void (__stdcall *TNewProfile_s)(const unsigned char *pData,
unsigned int nSize, void *pUserData);
```

I'm trying to insert my function 'NewProfile' in this parameter as follows:

```
RegisterCallback(STD_CALL, (void*)NewProfile, m_pLLT1);
```

But it says: 'Error: invalid type conversion'.

The function definition for 'NewProfile' is:

```
void __stdcall NewProfile(const unsigned char* pucData, unsigned int uiSize, void* pUserData){...}
```

Where is my error exactly? What can I do in order to fix it?

Comment: Please post complete error message. I suspect that `NewProfile` is a non-static member function or something else.

Comment: does `(void*)&NewProfile` work better?

Comment: Hi @VTT. Unfortunately that's the complete error message, sorry. However you were right with your assumption... I declared my function as static and now it works! Great! EDIT: I'm a new user so I can't upvote your comment, can you please write it on a answer? Thanks

Comment: Just a wild guess: Is it the `m_pLLT1` which causes the error? What type does it have? (May be, you need a `(void*)` for it as well.)

Comment: Which compiler are you using? Common compilers (g++, clang++ vc++) should output longer error message with error category. Please post complete build log then.

Comment: The error underlines the function type. `m_pLLT1` is okay

Comment: @VTT is IntelliSense who is giving me the error, and there's not a longer log. I'm sure about this.

Comment: 1. Don't trust IntelliSense. (Trust compiler output only.)  2. I remember having searched desperately type mismatch errors in VS2013 until I realized that the reported positions are sometimes... hmm... a little bit unprecise.

Comment: There is never any necessity to cast anything to `void *` in C++, except as a halfway-house to another cast. It is already an implicit cast. Any code you may find to the contrary is evidence of lack of understanding.

Comment: You can find real log in the `Output` window. IntelliSense is certainly far from perfect but it should not complain about this spot if it properly compiles.

Comment: @VTT In our productive projects, IntelliSense complains about a few things which compile _perfectly_ (without even any warning). ;-)

Comment: @Scheff It may even crash on some code, however in general I find it rather reliable. From my experience most of errors originate from  incorrect project configuration, circular / missing / indirect includes.

Comment: When you cast a function pointer, you’re almost certainly doing something wrong.  What’s the prototype of `RegisterCallback`?

Comment: @molbdnilo do you mean the declaration? In that case, it's the first code.

Comment: Please, **compile** the resp. file and copy/paste the error log message of the **compiler** regarding this. You will find it in the `Output` tab of VS.

Comment: Maybe it's just a copy-paste error in your post, but I see `_stdcall` and `__stdcall`. Do you have the correct amount of underscores in your actual code?

Comment: @mindriot yes, always two. Was a copypaste error.

Comment: Thanks to everybody, this issue is solved as I said to @VTT

Comment: @Citdar I missed that, sorry. That's a pretty strange interface - the second parameter would normally be a function pointer of the appropriate type. That is, one would expect it to be `TNewProfile_s`, not `void*`.

Comment: _I declared my function as static and now it works!_ If it is a pure function this shouldn't have any effect (concerning the reported issue). It would make sense if it is a class function. But if it is a class function would it work without preceding class scope? I have somehow the feeling that you left out something essential...

Comment: @EJP -- "There is never any necessity to cast anything to void *" -- a function pointer cannot be implicitly converted to a data pointer, `void*` or otherwise. That's partly because a function pointer does not have to be the same size as a data pointer, and allowing an implicit conversion could produce an invalid pointer.

Comment: @PeteBecker Exactly, so there is never any necessity to do it.

Comment: The cause of using (void *) is because the API from library indicates this kind of use. I'm agree with you, is a strange interface